# How is the SELinux MLS range restricted during user login?

Tags: security, pam, selinux

I'm trying to understand what logic determines whether a user can log in with a particular MLS sensitivity level. At first I suspected that pam_selinux.so reads the /etc/selinux/.../seusers file to understand which user is bound to which seuser and then restricts the user to sensitivities equal to or lower than the high component of the MLS range.

However, after scratching through its source code I found that, after asking the user if he would like to change their security context from the the default context, pam_selinux checks that the new MLS labels are appropriate by calling into the kernel policy.

The following code is in modules/pam_selinux/pam_selinux.c from the Ubuntu libpam-modules 1.1.1-4ubuntu2 package.

```
static int mls_range_allowed(pam_handle_t *pamh, security_context_t src, security_context_t dst, int debug)
{
  struct av_decision avd;
  int retval;
  unsigned int bit = CONTEXT__CONTAINS;
  context_t src_context = context_new (src);
  context_t dst_context = context_new (dst);
  context_range_set(dst_context, context_range_get(src_context));
  if (debug)
    pam_syslog(pamh, LOG_NOTICE, "Checking if %s mls range valid for  %s", dst, context_str(dst_context));

  retval = security_compute_av(context_str(dst_context), dst, SECCLASS_CONTEXT, bit, &avd);
  context_free(src_context);
  context_free(dst_context);
  if (retval || ((bit & avd.allowed) != bit))
    return 0;

  return 1;
}
```

It seems to me that this check is actually checked in the kernel policy, seen in the security_compute_av() call. This turned my understanding of SELinux login on my head.

So, could someone please explain:

- How is the validity of a user-chosen login security level determined?
- How exactly is that logic implemented in the policy, in pam_selinux, and in the kernel?

Currently, I'm not too interested in type enforcement multi, categories security, or role based access control, so no need to explain how those components are validated if they don't affect MLS sensitivities.

Comment: I understand your question, but I'm not sure why you are confused.  You are correct in your assessment that security_compute_av() does the real validation.  The AVC validates if the presented context makes sense and PAM is only responsible for telling the user in a nice way.  You pretty much answered your own question, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: *sigh* I wish I knew for sure what I was asking... SELinux folds my mind in half and I haven't been plugged into that source code for a while now.

Comment: What I was confused about, and still am, is why the kernel knows about *any* user security attributes. Usually this kind of decision regarding login is handled in user space (say: checking passwords, session limits, group membership, etc.). I suppose this question is also a lamentation that SELinux seems way to complicated, and takes that complexity straight into the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that I also share the "SELinux folds my brain in half" problem, I think I can help.  First and foremost, you need to remember the difference between discretionary access control and mandatory access control.  You also need to remember that user space defines a lot of things, but the kernel gets to enforce them.

First, here is a partial list of user space versus kernel space issues:

- User space defines a valid user ID, the kernel creates processes owned by that user ID (the number, not the name)
- User space puts permissions and ownership on a file on an ext3/4 file system, the kernel enforces access to that file based upon the file inode and every subsequent parent directory inode
- If two users share the same user ID in `/etc/passwd`, the kernel will grant them both the same privileges because enforcement is done by the numeric identifier, not the textual one
- User space requests a network socket to another host, the kernel isolates that conversation from others on the same system
- With SELinux, user space defines roles, logins, and users via `semanage` and the kernel compiles those down into a large Access Vector Cache (AVC) so that it can enforce role-based access control and mandatory access control
- Also under SELinux, a security administrator can use `semanage` to define a minimum and maximum security context.  If you are in a multi-level security (MLS) configuration, and during log in, the users picks some context, then the kernel measures that against the AVC to determine if it is allowed.

What would probably help this make sense is to be in a multi-level security configuration.  I took the class on SELinux and we touched it for about two hours.  Most people don't want to go there.  Ever.  I've been in an MLS configuration quite a bit, so I understand the reasoning behind the coding decision you were chasing, but I agree that tinkering with MLS is a pretty painful way to understand how and why PAM works like it does.

Discretionary Access Control (DAC) is where user space, especially non-root users, can define who can access data that they control and in what fashion.  Think file permissions.  Because users control it, there is a trivial amount of effort needed to allow one user to see processes and/or files owned by another user.  Normally, we don't care that much because a good administrator assumes that any one user could compromise the whole box and so all users are trusted equally.  This might be very little trust, but there is still *some* level of trust.

Mandatory Access Control (MAC) is where user space is not to be trusted.  Not all users are created equal.  From a non-MLS perspective, consider the case where you have a web server and a database server on the same hardware (it will never survive the Slashdot effect).  The only time the two processes communicate is over a dedicated connection channel over TCP.  Otherwise, they must not even know that the other exists.  We would operate them under two different contexts and the kernel will enforce the separation.  Even looking at the process table or wandering around the hard drive as root will not get you any closer unless you change contexts.

In an MLS configuration, I can't tell you how many times I've tried to get random combinations of sensitivity and context only to be rebuffed for picking an invalid combination.  It can be very frustrating because it takes a lot of exploring of your existing policy (`/etc/selinux/`*policy*`/src/policy/policy` under Red Hat 5) to know what it or is not allowed.

Under a Strict configuration, I can clearly see why all of this is overkill.  And that's simply because SELinux *is* overkill for simple situations.  It has other features though that partially redeem it, but chief among them is fine grained access control that enforces administrator-set permissions.  One area that this is used the most is in restricting service daemons to just their essential access needed.  It is painful to set up a new daemon, but it keeps trivial exploitations like a shared library exploit from going any further because the process in question may be assigned to a role that won't let it run non-daemon commands like `/bin/ls` or a shell.  Exploits don't do you much good in those situations.

Comment: I smiled when I read this because I give almost this exact speech to customers when we're trying to explain how it works and why its there. I already have the level grasp of SELinux. At work my job is to heavily scrutinize the legitimacy of security features of products, such as SELinux and that they're applied appropriately. So I often find myself digging a little bit more into the code and design than a developer or sysadmin might.

Comment: ...so, when I was commenting on login, this idea of user-subject binding (where some of the user's attributes are bound to a process) seems unclear and seems generally undocumented. And, I'm questioning why the user attributes (actually in this case the binding between user and seuser) are stored in the policy loaded inside the kernel instead of in a file like other such attributes (i.e. /etc/passwd).

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't able to fully guess your exposure level.  Not a lot of MLS tags here though so it might prove useful in the future.

Comment: I think that I have silently wondered the same things myself, but my Red Hat instructor filled me in that Red Hat has done a lot to get SELinux easier to configure over the years and that they've been forced to live with several design decisions.  He expressed regret that adding a new module requires that the whole policy be recompiled, but such was life.  Adding a new login or changing roles for an existing user requires that the whole policy be recompiled.  Yuck.  I'm glad that filesystem authors didn't act like this...